# Django append products in categories with same names

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

and im tying to append products to categories with same name For example this is my models.

***models.py***

```
class Category(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    parent_category = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='children', null=True, blank=True)


class Product(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, related_name = 'products')
```

***views.py***

```
#For Example I have Main Category Technic. that has 2 child categories (Mobile Phones and SmartPhones) and both have category Phone with same name See the Tree:
#Technic -> Mobile Phones -> Phone AND Technic -> SmartPhones -> Phone
```

Technic -> Mobile Phones -> Phone - Contains 4 products
Technic -> SmartPhones -> Phone - Contains 0 products

All im trying to do is to check if smallest(childest) category has same name take its produts and fetch to another Phone Category in this position

#Desired Result ->
Technic -> Mobile Phones -> Phone - Contains 4 products ( same products )
Technic -> SmartPhones -> Phone - Contains 4 products ( same products ) Because both last child cat names are the same.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to identify, when a category is lowest child. For example, check that no parent exists. Then get the set of categories with same headline and looping through lowest child categories, add all categories with same headline to each product.

```
for category in lowest_child_categories:
    # only if category has no parent
    if not category.parent_category_set.all().exists():

    # get all categories with same headline
    same_headlines = Categories.objects.filter(headline=category.headline)

    # for each associated product, add all other categories to product
    for product in category.products.all():
        for other_category in same_headlines:

            # only if no parent category exists
            if not other_category.parent_category_set.all().exists():

                # this will not duplicate association if already exists
                product.category.add(other_category)
```

This example will run some unnecessary. You can further fine-tune the algorithm for performance.

Comment: lowest_child_categories = Category.objects.filter(parent_category=None)
this will filter only parent categories which dont have parent_category am i right? not lowest child categories which dont have child categories

Comment: @Nika110, yes, you're right. In you logic, you define it the other way around. Adjusted the response.